# tensorflow: reduce_max function

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, deep-learning

consider the following code-

```
a=tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[1001,1002],[3,4]]), dtype=tf.float32)
b=tf.reduce_max(a,reduction_indices=[1], keep_dims=True)
with tf.Session():
   print b.eval()
```

What exactly is the purpose of keep_dims here? I tested quite a bit, and saw that the above is equivalent to-

```
b=tf.reduce_max(a,reduction_indices=[1], keep_dims=False)
b=tf.expand_dims(b,1)
```

I maybe wrong, but my guess is that if keep_dims is False, we get a 2D coloumn vector. And if keep_dims=True, we have a 2x1 matrix. But how are they different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reduce over one or more indices (i.e. dimensions of the tensor), you effectively reduce the rank of the tensor (i.e. its number of dimensions or, in other words, the number of indices you need in order to access an element of the tensor). By setting `keep_dims=True`, you are telling tensorflow to keep the dimensions over which you reduce. They will then have size 1, but they are still *there*. While a column vector and a nx1 matrix are conceptually the same thing, in tensorflow, these are tensors of rank 1 (you need a single index to access an element) and rank 2 (you need two indices to access an element), respectively.